# Can find recurse into some folders but not others in the same command?

Tags: command-line, directory, find

I want to use `find` to recurse through certain subfolders in `$HOME` but not in others in the same command. Is that possible?

To clarify, I'd like to recurse into `~/Desktop`, `~/Documents`, and `~/Dropbox`, but not into `~/.config` or `~/.dropbox` or `~/.cache`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can pass the directories you want to start from as multiple starting points to `find`.**

You want to use `find` to search a handful of specific directories, all of which *happen* to be subdirectories of your home directory:

> To clarify, I'd like to recurse into `~/Desktop`, `~/Documents`, and `~/Dropbox`, but not into `~/.config` or `~/.dropbox` or `~/.cache`.

So you can just pass those directories as starting points for `find`. We often use a single directory as a starting point, and it is often `.`, but `find` isn't limited to that.

```
find ~/Desktop ~/Documents ~/Dropbox -name my-file
```

Replace *`-name my-file`* with the rest of the `find` command (i.e., the tests and actions) you want to run.

This doesn't supply your home directory itself as a starting point to `find`, and since none of the directories it supplies contains your home directory--they are instead *contained by* it--files in your home directory that are not contained within any of those specific directories will not be found.

If these directories happen to be *all* the subdirectories of your home directory whose names don't start with `.`, then you can have your shell build the list for you:

```
find ~/*/ -name my-file
```

`*` matches any sequence of characters in a filename. The last trailing `/` causes only directories to be matched. By default, shells don't expand `*` to files whose names start with `.`. So unless you've enabled the `dotglob` shell option (or whatever your shell has for that, if your shell is not Bash), the list produced by `*` won't include the `.config`, `.dropbox`, or `.cache` subdirectories of your home directory.

Files and directories whose names start with `.` *and that reside within the directories passed as starting points* will still be found, of course.

Comment: But that then wouldn't find ~/.bash_aliases or ~/.bashrc or files created directly in $HOME. I tried sticking in '-maxdepth 0' but that prevented recursion altogether.

Comment: @DKBose No, because those files reside directly in your home directory, and your home directory is not one of the locations that `find` searches. It is only searching the locations specified as starting points, all of which are deeper than your home directory itself.

Comment: I'm using the default shell and haven't messed with ~/.bashrc.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear in the first place! I've substantially rewritten the question now.

Comment: @DKBose Ah, I think I misunderstood [that comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168888/can-find-recurse-into-some-folders-but-not-others-in-the-same-command/1168894#comment1950156_1168894). If I understand correctly now, you're saying you *want* to process files like `.bash_aliases.2019-08-27-18-41-25` that exist inside the directories you're searching. That's no problem--with the method given in my answer, `find` will still find and process files whose names start with `.` that exist anywhere inside your specified starting points (see edit). So I *think* this may still work fine for you.

Comment: `.bash_aliases.2019-08-27-18-41-25` would be the file created as a backup if identified by the `nwt` function.